# How to rewrite URL of custom post type without post type in URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I am working on a tour site. Where they have a custom post type built with a custom plugin.
That custom post type has base slug like "/destination/".$post->post_name.
They want to me to remove that base slug so that it could be only $post->post_name

I have tried a code from internet listed below.

It works for single level for that destination.
But when I have a parent destination like New York in United State America.
So it does not work.
Here is an example:

```
function update_destination_page_link_filter($post_link, $post, $leavename = null, $sample = null ) {
    if ( $post->post_type === 'destination' ) {
        $post_link = str_replace('/destination/', '/', $post_link);
        if($post->post_parent !== 0){
            $parent_slug = get_parent_link($post->post_parent, '');
            $post_link = '/'.$parent_slug.$post->post_name;
        }
        $post_link = update_url_base( $post, $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'update_destination_page_link_filter', 1, 3 );


function allow_destination_direct_by_name( $query ) {
     // Only noop the main query
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    // Only noop our very specific rewrite rule match
    if ( 2 != count( $query->query )
        || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) )
        return;

    // 'name' will be set if post permalinks are just post_name, otherwise the page rule will match
    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'destination', 'page' ) );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'allow_destination_direct_by_name', 1);
```

Single Level
http://siteurl/united-state-america works well
http://siteurl/united-state-america/new-york not working. It should open the new-york location page but it is showing 404
It may also be more specification in location
Like http://siteurl/united-state-america/new-york/brooklyn

Answer (score 1):

The following code may help you, in this regards.

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_post_type_link', 10, 3);
function my_post_type_link($permalink, $post, $leavename) {

    if  ($post->post_type == <your-post-type>) 
    {
        $p_name=$post->post_name;
        $parent_slug = get_parent_link($post->post_parent, '');
        if (isset($parent_slug) && !empty($parent_slug)) 
        {
            $permalink = home_url( "" . $parent_slug . "/" . $p_name . "/");
        }
    }

    return $permalink;

}

add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'my_rewrite_rules_array');
function my_rewrite_rules_array($rules) {

    $rules = array('([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=<your-post-type>&name=$matches[2]&meta=$matches[1]') + $rules;

    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: Hi, It workes but one issue.
It may also be more specification in location Like http://siteurl/united-state-america/new-york/brooklyn

So for the third location... it is not working.

Comment: Mainly, I need the last match only. So if I get there $matches[(last_match)] whether it is 2 or 3 or 4 whatever the last one.
That will solve my problem.

Comment: Also, It is not working for multiple CPT. so let's say I have the destination, Information, and place.

Comment: You have to add more specification for function "my_post_type_link" and also need to write another function for the rule with other post type.